# NSProcessInfo of a pid

Tags: macos, sandbox

I have a pid of a process. I want to check if that application is sandboxed or not. I want to check it by checking APP_SANDBOX_CONTAINER_ID environment variable. For that I need NSProcessInfo of another process so that I can look up into NSDictionary and check that environment variable. As NSProcessInfo is read only, how can i generate NSProcessInfo of another process from its pid and check for sandbox status.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be better to use the `sandbox_check` private API to see if the pid in question is a sandboxed process. This is what activity monitor does. If you really wanted to get another process's environment variables you would need to issue a `sysctl` system call with `KERN_PROCARGS`/`KERN_PROCARGS2` and parse through the returned struct.

You can use `sandbox_check` like so

```
extern int sandbox_check(pid_t, const char *, int);
...
...
isSandboxed = sandbox_check(pid, NULL, 0);  // 1 if sandboxed, 0 otherwise
```